# How to pass dependencies to an enqueued class through its constructor in Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, hangfire

I have a class called Car

```cs
public class Car : ICar
{
    private readonly Driver driver;
    private readonly EngineInfo engineInfo;
    private readonly Logger logger;

    public Car(Driver driver, EngineInfo engineInfo, Logger logger)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.engineInfo = engineInfo;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Drive()
    {
       // Your Drive() logic here, using the driver, engineInfo, and logger objects.
    }
}
```

I am trying to use hangfire to call Car.Drive(). using

```
Client.Enqueue<Car>(c => c.Drive());
```

When I do this, it is always asking for Car to have a parameterless constructor. When i add it, i can no longer pass in a driver, engineinfo, or logger to the object before drive is called. I have tried JobActivators too, but to no avail.

Can someone with more HangFire knowledge help me out? I want to be able to call a ***parameterized*** Car constructor so i can give it a driver, etc., *then* call drive.

I have watched almost a dozen tutorials on hangfire and they have all avoided this part of the process. The jobs they enqueue are never custom data type method calls.

I have read tons of stackoverflow posts and github issue threads and tried all of those solutions, but never gotten a straight answer i can apply to the pre-existing codebase.

Comment: Are you working with the BackgroundJob class?

Comment: Are you using a Dependency Injection framework ?
If you want a specfic object for Car, with custom properties, you could use a factory

Comment: @jbl i was told to avoid DI frameworks like Ninject, as it is just another library to update and check in on for our project. I would like to stay isolated within Hangfire's methodology.

Comment: @RossBush we have a BackgroundJobClient and BackgroundJobServer in the program. The server object is never referenced after instantiation, and the client obj is used to enqueue Car.Drive()

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work with DI directly when using Hangfire. It can be a separate part of the of you application. Hangfire is simply used to invoke methods that can be part of a class that does get dependencies injected in its constructor.

If you registered the `Driver`, `EngineInfo`, and `Logger` classes correctly with the DI framework, then in the example above, the the dependencies should be already satisfied when the `Drive()` method is called.